# Running SQL job: The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, authentication, jobs, logins

I have two databases in different servers (server1 , server2)

**server1: 
Login : login1 /  password :123 /member of sysadmin (user user1,password:pass)** 

**server2 :
Login :login1 /   password :123 /member of sysadmin (user user1,password:pass)**

when I try to connect to **server1's linked server** from server2 , I can do it without issue in stored procedures.
but when I try to run sp in sql jobs in server2, this issue happens:

> The job failed.The Job was invoked by User user1. 
>   Executed as user: Server2\Administrator. Login failed. The login is
>   from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows
>   authentication. [SQLSTATE 28000] (Error 18452).  The step failed.

*(the owner of sql job is Login1)*

Whats the point?Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The job is executed as the SQL Agent account, unless you have configured a proxy.  The owner of the job is irrelevant as long as the SQL Agent account can verify that the owner is valid (still exists in AD/SQL).

Verify which account is running the job, either the SQL Agent account or the Proxy account. Then verify that account has permissions into the linked server.  Or create a proxy account for this job.

Comment: thanks for reply. I set user account to one administrator user , the error is changed to **"Executed as user: dbo. Remote access not allowed for Windows NT user activated by SETUSER. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7410).  The step failed."**

Comment: Is the owner of the job "sa"?  How is the linked server configured for authentication?  Check out this link.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811031